# PHP - days between today and birthday

Tags: php

I'm working on function to get know how old person is by the given birthday and how long it will take to another birthday, but can't find a way how to get these days between.

There is my code

```
<form action="Vek.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="prom1" />
<input type="text" name="prom2" />
<input type="text" name="prom3" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["prom1"])) {
$prom1 = $_GET["prom1"];
}else{
    $prom1 = '1';
}

if (isset($_GET["prom2"])) {
$prom2 = $_GET["prom2"];
}else{
    $prom2 = '1';
}

if (isset($_GET["prom3"])) {
    $prom3 = $_GET["prom3"];
}else{
    $prom3 = '2000';
}
      echo "Zadal jste datum: ".$prom1.".".$prom2.".".$prom3;
echo "<br>";
 $datum = Date("j/m/Y", Time());  //today's date
echo "<br>";
echo('Dnešní datum: '.$datum);

echo "<br>";
$test = mktime(0,0,0,$prom2, $prom1, $prom3);
$narozeniny = date("j/m/Y", $test); //day of birthday
echo "<br>";
echo ('Narozeniny: '.$narozeniny);

function zjistiVek($prom1,$prom2,$prom3) //function to find how old are you
{
    $vek = time() - mktime(0, 0, 0, $prom2, $prom1, $prom3);
    $vek = $vek / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    $vek = floor($vek);
    return $vek;
}
echo "<br>";
echo('Momentálně je Vám: '.zjistiVek($prom1,$prom2, $prom3).' let');
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is and the specific (smaller) piece of code that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) classes here to easily get a diff and format it however you want. Example:

```
$dt1 = new DateTime('2015-01-01'); // an arbitrary time
$dt2 = new DateTime(); // right now's time
$diff = $dt1->diff($dt2); // a DateInterval object
echo $diff->format("%R%a"); // print the difference, in days
```

Diff function: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Format function: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php